# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file Why this happens? Automate boring stuff with python book

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

## Am begginer Following the book  [**Automate Boring Stuff with python**](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter9/)

### **The First project of the Chapter Showing as to make Random Quiz genarator with Random ,write, read, close and open**

> ## This is my code

```py
#! python3
# randomQuizGenerator.py - Creates quizzes with questions and answers in
# random order, along with the answer key.
import random
   # The quiz data. Keys are states and values are their capitals.
capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
   'Arkansas': 'Little Rock', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Colorado': 'Denver',
   'Connecticut': 'Hartford', 'Delaware': 'Dover', 'Florida': 'Tallahassee',
   'Georgia': 'Atlanta', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu', 'Idaho': 'Boise', 'Illinois':
   'Springfield', 'Indiana': 'Indianapolis', 'Iowa': 'Des Moines', 'Kansas':
   'Topeka', 'Kentucky': 'Frankfort', 'Louisiana': 'Baton Rouge', 'Maine':
   'Augusta', 'Maryland': 'Annapolis', 'Massachusetts': 'Boston', 'Michigan':
   'Lansing', 'Minnesota': 'Saint Paul', 'Mississippi': 'Jackson', 'Missouri':
   'Jefferson City', 'Montana': 'Helena', 'Nebraska': 'Lincoln', 'Nevada':
   'Carson City', 'New Hampshire': 'Concord', 'New Jersey': 'Trenton', 
   'NewMexico': 'Santa Fe', 'New York': 'Albany',
   'North Carolina': 'Raleigh', 'North Dakota': 'Bismarck', 
   'Ohio': 'Columbus', 'Oklahoma': 'Oklahoma City',
   'Oregon': 'Salem', 'Pennsylvania': 'Harrisburg', 'Rhode Island': 'Providence',
   'South Carolina': 'Columbia', 'South Dakota': 'Pierre', 'Tennessee':
   'Nashville', 'Texas': 'Austin', 'Utah': 'Salt Lake City', 'Vermont':
   'Montpelier', 'Virginia': 'Richmond', 'Washington': 'Olympia', 
   'WestVirginia': 'Charleston', 'Wisconsin': 'Madison', 'Wyoming': 'Cheyenne'}

   # Generate 35 quiz files.
for quizNum in range(35):
  # Create the quiz and answer key files.
  quizFile = open(f'capitalsquiz{quizNum + 1}.txt', 'w')
  answerKeyFile = open(f'capitalsquiz_answers{quizNum + 1}.txt', 'w')
     # Write out the header for the quiz.
  quizFile.write('Name:\n\nDate:\n\nPeriod:\n\n')
  quizFile.write((' ' * 20) + f'State Capitals Quiz (Form{quizNum + 1})')
  quizFile.write('\n\n')

  # Shuffle the order of the states.
  states = list(capitals.keys())
  random.shuffle(states)
   # Loop through all 50 states, making a question for each.
  for questionNum in range(50):

         # Get right and wrong answers.
      correctAnswer = capitals[states[questionNum]]
      wrongAnswers = list(capitals.values())
      del wrongAnswers[wrongAnswers.index(correctAnswer)]
      wrongAnswers = random.sample(wrongAnswers, 3)
      answerOptions = wrongAnswers + [correctAnswer]
      random.shuffle(answerOptions)

        # Write the question and the answer options to the quiz file.
      quizFile.write(f'{questionNum + 1}. What is the capital of{states[questionNum]}?\n')
      for i in range(4):
        quizFile.write(f"    {'ABCD'[i]}. { answerOptions[i]}\n")
        quizFile.write('\n')

      # Write the answer key to a file.
      answerKeyFile.write(f"{questionNum + 1}.{'ABCD'[answerOptions.index(correctAnswer)]}")
      quizFile.close()
      answerKeyFile.close()
```

> Here is what the program does:

1. Creates 35 different quizzes
2. Creates 50 multiple-choice questions for each quiz, in random order
   Provides the correct answer and three random wrong answers for each question, in random order
3. Writes the quizzes to 35 text files
4. Writes the answer keys to 35 text files

> This means the code will need to do the following:

1. Store the states and their capitals in a dictionary
2. Call open(), write(), and close() for the quiz and answer key text files
3. Use random.shuffle() to randomize the order of the questions and multiple-choice options

## But this Code gives A error

> ### ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

> > > **Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "/home/hp/Documents/Developement/pob/ch9/randomQuizGenarotor.py", line 50, in 
> > > quizFile.write(f'{questionNum + 1}. What is the capital of{states[questionNum]}?\n')
> > > ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.**

## When I remove the code it works

```py
      quizFile.close()
      answerKeyFile.close()
```

## But there was some Issues

## I want to do with it

Comment: You close both file at the end of the first loop, so they're closed when you enter the second loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `close()` function is inside a for loop so after the first iteration it will close the files. Move the `close()` function outside of the for